# Which paths are there to use during installation of CentOS with libvirt?

Tags: centos

With libvirt, I can for example pass a file to the installation of Ubuntu:

```
virt-install ... --initrd-inject preseed.cfg \
                 --initrd-inject ubuntu-sysprep.sh ..
```

which then goes to the installation process' file system root. Then, there is a target file system under "/target" where I then copy and run this file to during a post-install section of the init script preseed.cfg I've submitted.

```
d-i preseed/late_command string cp /ubuntu-sysprep.sh /target/ubuntu-sysprep.sh; in-target sh /ubuntu-sysprep.sh
```

Now what is the equivalent of the /target/ path in CentOS 8 to put files you want to ship with the virtually installed system?

Comment: Did you end up with an answer for this question? Would recommend answering it yourself, if you did.